# VIM command to explore buffers

Tags: vim

I often use the command :Explore to switch to another file. I also use a lot the command :buffer to switch between previously opened files, but it is not always convenient when a lot of files are opened.

Is there a way to display a list of all opened files (buffers) in the current window, in a "explore" way, without using plugin?

Comment: Why _not_ use a plugin?

Comment: I try to avoid installing too much extensions and it seems to be a quite basic feature.

Comment: @srjjio The following map is a little time saver:  `cnoremap ls<cr> <c-u>ls<cr>:br`. Now typing `:ls<cr>` will show the buffer list. Then you can either type a buffer number, `{num}<cr>`, or hit `<esc>` to go back to the current buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:help :ls` is the closest you can get with basic built-in tools.

Comment: Not that I was expected but it helps a bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend creating a normal map like this in your `~/vimrc` file.

```
" list buffers and jump to a chosen one
nnoremap <Leader>b :ls<CR>:b<Space>
```

It triggers your `<Leader>` plus <kbd>b</kbd> to execute two commands at once, first it shows all open buffers, then it allows you to type the buffer number to open it. It wort reading `:h leader`.